# is it possible to enable Allow floating notification after App installation automatically through code?

Tags: android, permissions, notifications

[app info - notifications - notification categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0WxP.jpg)

I am checking in android 13 poco device. Checked documentation but cannot found right solution to this issue. I need to enable this by default.

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" This permission not working for this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not possible to programmatically enable floating notifications for your app on the user’s device. This is a setting that is controlled by the user and Android does not provide a way for developers to change this setting programmatically. In Android 13, we need to get runtime permission for notification. And also you have to intent user to notification permission settings screen to made user to opt in for floating notification.